# OSX 10.7 Precompile Errors in new Xcode Projects

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to build a new Xcode project targeting the 10.7 Mac SDK (and using llvm 3.1) and am getting a lot of parse errors during the precompile phase.

All of the Cocoa Foundation files are causing parse errors e.g.

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFString.h:525:174: error: expected function body after function declarator
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFError.h:68:43: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
> CF_EXPORT const CFStringRef kCFErrorURLKey                          CF_AVAILABLE(10_7, 5_0);    // Key to identify associated URL in userInfo.  Typically one of this or kCFErrorFilePathKey is provided.

If I switch back to using 10.6 everything seems to compile and run fine.

I've attempted to remove and re-install dev tools using:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools -mode=all
```

... and then re-installing Xcode 4.3.1, but my 10.7 builds of any new project still fail.

Has anyone seen a similar issue with Xcode 4.3+ and the 10.7 SDK.  And what other steps should I try and take to clean/install the dev tools/Xcode?

I've uploaded the build log to http://pastebin.com/ahYzhrww.

Comment: Do you mean that you get these errors when your precompiled prefix header is getting built? If so, what is in that `*.pch` file, and what languages are you using in your project? (Objective-C, C, C++, Objective-C++, ...)

Comment: The .pch file contains a single import for the cocoa.h file.

This is the base template provided by XCode.  I've literally created a new Cocoa application and the initial build fails if the target is set to 10.7.

I've uploaded the full build log to http://pastebin.com/ahYzhrww

Comment: Are you using the version of Xcode from the App Store?

Comment: Yes, I'm using XCode 4.3.1 installed from the App Store.

Comment: Is it possible to make a new project, save it and upload it somewhere? Also, does it compile with LLVM GCC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this not too long ago. These steps resolved it for me:

- Remove Xcode.app from /Applications
- Rename /Developer to /Devoper-old
- Reinstall Xcode from the Mac App Store.

In XCode, open the Xcode menu and choose Open Developer Tools, More developer tools...

to download the rest of the developer tools.